Normals only invert when I export my mesh to unity with armature
I'm making a belt for a character I already have. For some reason, the belt's normals are flipped ONLY when I data transfer, and give it vertex groups. When it's a static mesh, it exports fine, and it's normals are okay. The normals in blender are as they should be - blue is out, red is in. I can flip / recalculate the normals all day if I wanted. I'm at my wits end here. Apparently i'm the first person to ever have this problem.


Krentitst Hello and welcome, it could be very helpful if you post your.blend Here: https://blend-exchange.com/

If your object is manifold, all faces should be blue (or red). But you should not have blue AND red at the same time. Could you try this check: Select ‣ Select All by Trait ‣ Non-Manifold ?
